Getting import error from import `to_map_style_dataset`
I'm just started studying the annotated transformer. And I got an error with importing.
The error indicates importing:
from torchtext.data.functional import to_map_style_dataset

has this info:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[12], line 12
     10 import pandas as pd
     11 import altair as alt
---> 12 from torchtext.data import to_map_style_dataset
     13 from torch.utils.data import DataLoader
     14 from torchtext.vocab import build_vocab_from_iterator

File /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torchtext/__init__.py:18
     15     _WARN = False
     17 # the following import has to happen first in order to load the torchtext C++ library
---> 18 from torchtext import _extension  # noqa: F401
     20 _TEXT_BUCKET = "https://download.pytorch.org/models/text/"
     22 _CACHE_DIR = os.path.expanduser(os.path.join(_get_torch_home(), "text"))

File /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torchtext/_extension.py:64
     59     # This import is for initializing the methods registered via PyBind11
     60     # This has to happen after the base library is loaded
     61     from torchtext import _torchtext  # noqa
---> 64 _init_extension()

File /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torchtext/_extension.py:58, in _init_extension()
     55 if not _mod_utils.is_module_available("torchtext._torchtext"):
     56     raise ImportError("torchtext C++ Extension is not found.")
...
    378     self._handle = handle

OSError: dlopen(/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torchtext/lib/libtorchtext.so, 0x0006): Symbol not found: __ZN3c105ErrorC1ENSt3__112basic_stringIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEENS1_9allocatorIcEEEES7_PKv
  Referenced from: <5436ECC1-6F45-386E-B542-D5F76A22B52C> /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torchtext/lib/libtorchtext.so
  Expected in:     <69A84A04-EB16-3227-9FED-383D2FE98E93> /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/lib/libc10.dylib
Output is truncated. View as a scrollable element or open in a text editor. Adjust cell output settings...

is it about the versions? How can I fix it?
Thanks in advance.
